# Sole software engineer for a small company. How to handle deployment?

Tags: git, github, deployment, automation, installer

I'm the only software engineer for a small company and I want to make my deployment process more robust because I can't work away from my dedicated workstation with my current process. I only make proprietary, internal software for Windows that is used by employees using Visual Studio.

My current process is:

1. Code
2. Test
3. Commit and push to branch
4. Pull request, merge to master
5. Build the [installer project](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) in Visual Studio (Generates an msi file)
6. Run a python script to silently copy new application files to a shared network folder
7. [AutoUpdater.NET](https://github.com/ravibpatel/AutoUpdater.NET) checks for new files and updates other employees' software as necessary

Is there Github workflow actions that can automate all this? How do other companies deploy internal software? Really looking for low-budget/free options since this is a really small company. I'm basically looking to deploy this internal software to my company network/workstations, from home.

Comment: It seems you already automated most of the tasks which can be automated (1-4 cannot be automated, obviously. Steps 5 and 6 might be combined into one step, and "step 7" seems to be already an automatism which does not require manual intervention of yours). So please clarify where you see further potential.

Comment: @DocBrown I would like to be able to automatically build and deploy every time there is a push/merge to the master branch without having to physically click "Build" in visual studio, upload the files to our remote network, and then execute the python script to deploy it all. Is what I want to achieve this possible?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio w/Azure DevOps Server? Or is your remote GitHub ?

Comment: Visual Studio builds can be automated by using the command line interface of `devenv.exe`, or by using `msbuild.exe`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914030/automate-builds-in-net  Making a batch file or Python script to combine this into one step is not really hard. And I think you should plan for an integration tests *after* merging to master.

Comment: @kryz: What you are looking for is called continuous deployment. And yes, you can use GitHub workflows for that. Larger organizations typically have their own CI/CD (continuous integration and continuous deployment) servers, but for a small organization using a provider like GitHub is a good solution.

Comment: @IanW my remote is GitHub, not using devops but I will look into it

Comment: @DocBrown Thanks for the suggestion. Devenv looks interesting! I’m currently using Python to run msbuild already but to me it sounds like the process could be improved still

Comment: @kryz: if msbuild works for your case, I would recommend to use it. Running "devenv.exe" by command line is sometimes required for compatibility reasons, but it has a bigger startup time than msbuild.